# Copying directories in linux only if it contains the specified file

Tags: command-line, cp

I need to make a copy of all the folders under /parent (into a new location) but only if it has 123.dat - in which case I need to copy the folder too, but none of the other files it contains.

So that this:

```
|parent
|    |a
|    |    123.dat
|    |    456.dat
|    |b
|    |    123.dat
|    |    789.dat
|    |c
|    |    456.dat
|    |    789.dat
```

becomes:

```
|parent
|    |a
|    |    123.dat
|    |b
|    |    123.dat
```

How do I do this in linux? This area is not my expertise and so far I have no success with my attempts to search for something similar.

Comment: Do you need to make a copy of parent in another location too, or will parent be the destination and have a new name?

Comment: No, the source folders remain the same, I need to make a copy of parent in another location.

Comment: You could copy "parent" then delete everything that's not 123.dat using something like `find . -type f -not -name "123.dat" -ls` (replace 'ls' with 'delete' to do the deletion) very simply.

Comment: @pbhj This is a simple solution indeed and it works, but this is just an example and I need to copy almost 700Gb of data and copying the entire folder and then deleting it would be very expensive.

Comment: Somehow I knew that was going to be the case @Chillax.  ;o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**File/Folder structure:**

```
$ find src | sort
src
src/a
src/a/123.dat
src/a/456.dat
src/b
src/b/123.dat
src/b/768.dat
src/c
src/c/456.dat
src/c/768.dat
```

---

**Copy matching files, preserving relative path (shallow, not going deeper than 1 folder):**

***Command:***

```
$ (cd src && cp -v --parents -- */123.dat ../dest)
```

***Output:***

```
a -> ../dest/a
'a/123.dat' -> '../dest/a/123.dat'
b -> ../dest/b
'b/123.dat' -> '../dest/b/123.dat'
```

- I used a subshell with `(` and `)` in order not to change the original working directory when using `cd`. I had to enter `src` before executing `cp` in order to *not* create `src/` as base dir in `dest`.
- Will not work with file counts higher than the argument limit of bash (usually around 65k, if I'm not mistaken)

---

**Alternative approach (using `find` with adjustable depth limit):**

***Command:***

```
$ (cd src && find . -maxdepth 2  -type f -name '123.dat' -exec cp -v -t "../dest" --parents {} +)
```

***Output:***

```
./b -> ../dest/./b
'./b/123.dat' -> '../dest/./b/123.dat'
./a -> ../dest/./a
'./a/123.dat' -> '../dest/./a/123.dat'
```

***Notes:***

- I used a subshell with `(` and `)` in order not to change the original working directory when using `cd`. I had to enter `src` before executing `find` in order to *not* create `src/` as base dir in `dest`.
- I specified `-type f` to make sure only files with name `123.dat` are considered, not directories that happen to have that name

---

**Alternative approach (using `rsync`, without depth limitation):**

***Command:***

```
$ rsync -rv --include=123.dat --include='*/' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs src/ dest
```

***Output:***

```
building file list ... done
created directory dest
./
a/
a/123.dat
b/
b/123.dat

sent 205 bytes  received 90 bytes  590.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

***Double check:***

```
$ find dest
dest
dest/b
dest/b/123.dat
dest/a
dest/a/123.dat
```

***Notes:***

- The trailing `/` of `src/` is intentional, so that only the contents of the folder are copied, not the folder itself.
- `--exclude='*'` excludes everything by default
- `--include='*/` overrides the exclude and includes all folders
- `--include='123.dat'` overrides the exclude and includes files (and folders) with names '123.dat'
- `--prune-empty-dirs` makes sure no empty folders are created (e.g. `c`)

Comment: The destination shouldn't copy all the files - only the ones named 123.dat - but I guess this copies everything?

Comment: You're right, I didn't really read the second part of your question I guess, sorry. So you want to copy only the matching files while keeping the directory structure, gotcha. Do you need this to work for more than 1 level?

Comment: You are right. And only 1 level is required

Comment: Ok, cool. I added a different approach now, using rsync, which actually should work for *any* depth. I looked if I could somehow force-limit the depth, not knowing whether you actually need that or not - but couldn't find a good solution to that yet.

Comment: PS: I now also added a different approach using find (that can be depth-limited, if needed).

Comment: Haha, I just realized the my find thing is the same as `(cd src && cp -v --parents */123.dat ../dest)`

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to make a new version of the parent directory in the new location, then copy across the subdirectories if they contain 123.dat. This uses the Bash shell's globbing feature to find the subdirectories so will only work on directories immediately below parent. in the example I'll assume parent is in a directory called `/location1/` and will be moving to `/location2/`:

```bsh
mkdir -p /location2/parent
for d in /location1/parent/*
  do if [[ -e "$d"/123.dat ]]; then
    cp -r "$d" /location2/parent
  done
fi
```

As a CLI one-liner that would be:

```bsh
mkdir -p /location2/parent; for d in /location1/parent/*; do if [[ -e "$d"/123.dat ]]; then cp -r "$d" /location2/parent; done; fi
```

It's possible to improve this by using `find` to make it more efficient and add multi level subdirectories, or by putting the source directory, target directory and file to search for into variables. This should do what you need for now.

To copy a directory if it contains a particular file, but not copy any of the other files there's a less than elegant solution which requires `cd`ing into the source directory, the `cd -` part at the end returns you to your original directory:

```bsh
mkdir -p /location2/parent; cd /location1/parent/ && for d in ./*; do if [[ -e "$d"/123.dat ]]; then cp --parents "$d"/123.dat /location2/parent/; fi ; done; cd -
```

As a multi-line:

```bsh
mkdir -p /location2/parent
cd /location1/parent/ && for d in ./*
  do 
    if [[ -e "$d"/123.dat ]]; then 
      cp --parents "$d"/123.dat /location2/parent/
    fi
  done
cd -
```

Comment: How do I use this as a single line bash script?

Comment: Also is it possible to match multiple files, for eg 123.dat and 456.dat ?

Comment: Yes. It depends whether you want to copy if both files exist of if either file exists, you can use the and operator `&&` or the or operator `||` within the if statement.

Comment: I think it takes d as /location1/parent and not the sub-folders? Doesn't seem to do anything for me

Comment: ok, but the loop I could see is getting executed only once for `/location1/parent/*` (echo before do if)and nothing happens

Comment: Indeed I am doing the echo right before if (after do) . I still see the literal /location1/parent/* being printed out - there are directories with files under /location1/parent. I am executing this in the parent folder of location1

Comment: Indeed it was the path, absolute path is working. But then I guess it is copying all the files in the folder if 123.dat exists ? Whereas I want only 123.dat to be copied.

Comment: Hence the sample :-) . I get this now, `cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory`

Comment: This is probably a path problem again, the path in the `cp` command with `/location2/parent` must be the full absolute path to the directory you made with the `mkdir` command at the start, otherwise it can be the relative path from `/location1/parent`.